Does Ghostscript.Net support Cancellation Tokens? If so how can I make an Image Extraction task cancelable?
I am currently doing something like this:
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ())
{
    using (rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer ())
    {
        //rasterize.
        rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add ("-dNEWPDF=false");
        rasterizer.Open (inputMS, gvi, false);
        System.Drawing.Image preview = rasterizer.GetPage(200, 1);
        preview.Save (ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        result = ms.ToArray ();
        ms.Close ();        
    }
    rasterizer.Close ();
}

I see that Ghostscript itself supports registering a cancellation callback function, can I somehow use GHostscript.net to allow me to cancel the rasterizer.GetPage call?
